# Neon tetra went missing?

Tags: aquarium, fish, lost-pet

I bought two neon tetras today and added them into the fish tank with all the needed procedures. One hour I see both tetras and I come back to only find one. I've moved around every arrangement and haven't found it. What happened?!

Comment: You need to put here more information, in special the tank capacity, number and types of the the other fishs if you have more fishes.

Comment: A fish doesn't disappear. A tetra will not devour another tetra. Look around, behind decorations or plants, at the bottom, at the surface, inside the filter. Around the tank if you don't have a lid. Do you have bigger fishes in there?

Comment: After finding Nemo. Finding Neon an exciting new movie

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, I found it stuck inside one of the decorations I bought at Walmart. It died. I already took out the decoration and I'm not putting it back into the tank.